# Light intensity on plain from angle

Tags: directx, lighting, normals, angles

Given a vector (v) for the direction of light and a vector (n) for the normal of a plain.

How can I calculate a rudimentary intensity value (i) where

```
When (v) points at (n) directly/face on (i) = 1.0
When (v) points away from (n) (i) = 0.0
And everything else in-between
```

For now we don't need to account for reflection, or any other side effect of a plain.

Has anyone got any ides on how to do this?

I am using DirectX11 for this but I would prefer a solution that I can implement independently.

Comment: Isn't it just v dot n?

Comment: @immibis yes, or in the given convention `max(0,dot(-v,n))` but yes.

Comment: Yes it is immibis, FYI I have bumped into a few examples now that use dot(v,n) * .5 + .5   While not quite the same thing you then avoid the need for an "if / max"